# panic: errors: *target must be interface or implement error in Go

Tags: go, error-handling

I am making a json unmarshalling error handling function in Go:

```
import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func parseJSONError(err error) {
    var uterr json.UnmarshalTypeError

    if errors.As(err, &uterr) {
        //...
        return
    }

    var serr json.SyntaxError

    if errors.As(err, &serr) {
        //...
        return
    }
}
```

But there is a panic in `errors.As()`: `panic: errors: *target must be interface or implement error`.

What is target we can learn from the [github.com/pkg/errors documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#As):

`func As(err error, target interface{}) bool`

The problem is that both `json.UnmarshalTypeError` and `json.SyntaxError` actually implement the `error` interface. We can learn it from the [encoding/json documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json). So I do not have any idea what I am doing wrong. Even explicit casting `uterr` and `serr` to the `interface{}` does not save the situation.

The panic occurs in both `github.com/pkg/errors` and standard `errors` packages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation of [`errors.As`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#As) states:

> As will panic if target is not a non-nil **pointer to** either **a type that implements error**, or to any interface type. As returns false if err is nil.

So you have to consider the following:

1. `json.UnmarshalTypeError` does not implement `error`.
2. `*json.UnmarshalTypeError` does, because the method `Error() string` has a pointer receiver ([docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#UnmarshalTypeError.Error))
3. based on the documentation, `errors.As` wants a pointer to what implements `error`, so you need **`**json.UnmarshalTypeError`**

Change the code to:

```
uterr := &json.UnmarshalTypeError{}
if errors.As(err, &uterr) {
    // ...
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can simply add `-unsafeptr` flag. Like so:

```
go vet -unsafeptr ./...
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue of the runtime panic?